# Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell 3 Missing icons in dropdown menus in Eclipse

Tags: 14.04, icons, eclipse, menu

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell 3. Icons don't appear in dropdown menus in Eclipse. I have just follow many tutorial and wiki to solve problem. Nothing I've tried works. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Finally found a solution:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/

GOTO:
dconf-editor -> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings

Add
{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}

to what is there.